# how to use odatagen for odata webservices

Tags: odata

Anyone can tell me how to use odatagen for odata webservices. I am new in using odata services. Can anyone give me understand with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `./odatagen` from Terminal in the directory where the file is located to get the list of commands:

```
Usage: odatagen [/uri=<data service Uri> | /metadata=<service metadata file>] [/out=<output file path>][/auth=windows|acs /u=username /p=password [/sn=servicenamespace /at=applies_to]][/ups=yes|no]
```

A basic usage may be:

```
./odatagen /uri=https://192.168.138.137/Services/OData.svc /out=/Users/yourUser/Desktop/
```

This will generate the Entities files in the specified directory.

The ODataSDK also contains a documentation set.